# How to create irregular shapes with round corners

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, effects

[image]

I found a logo of a company named Ibbt. As you can see, there is a separation between elements (the shapes in the left). Can anybody tell how to create such effect in Illustration?

Comment: Highly irrelevant, but it turns out that `ibbt` is now called `iMinds` http://www.iminds.be/ -- I think you should google: `Pentool` tutorials and `Pathfinder` tutorials for illustrator.

Comment: joonas i think u didn't get mu question. I want to learn how can we make fine details like in the logo not outer part

Comment: I guarantee that if you learn to use pen tool and pathfinder, you will be able to do fan of colors just like that. Plus they are super useful tools.

Comment: again u are not getting.i know how to use pentool .what i am saying is there is details in logo that is  what i want .The edges between logos .

Comment: I guess I don't understand, then.

Comment: Not getting it here either.

Comment: Probably my fault, I edited thinking he was referring to the color inside the shape, but looks like it's the shapes themselves the OP is talking about. Sorry, re-editing.

Comment: Given that my answer was accepted I'm not sure that the edit helped clarify. I understood it as OP wanting to know how to do the layered color effect and how to mask it in Illustrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual fanning looks like layered transparency. Meaning, you maybe start with a rectangle, cut it down to size, and make more on top until you are fully opaque.

I'd look into the [Draw Inside](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6269a.html#WSf01dbd23413dda0e1e23acb6124476da654-7ff3) feature in Illustrator. That way, you create your fanned look and then cut and paste the shape(s) into whatever shape.

I'll try and expand this answer later, but I hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Draw your shape and adjust its transparency.
[image]

Layer additional shapes on top of the transparent shape (I just copied and pasted)

[image]

Once you're done, select the shape you want to paste your fan shape into and select "Draw Inside"
[image]

Now just copy and paste your fan shape with the "draw inside" shape selected.
[image]

**EDIT**

You should be able to do this with multiple shapes as well by grouping them together before selecting "Draw "Inside'.

Comment: somewhat i am understanding u .It i will help me when u show me in image form .

Comment: I added images, let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

Could surely be done with the pen tool and pathfinder tool in illustrator.

It would be much easier to use a layer mask in photoshop however.

That said, if you're creating a new, important logo, for anything other than a one off website, you're better off not taking short cuts and refining every detail of the logo in illustrator so you have it as a vector file for future use. Otherwise, assuming the logo doesn't change and the company doesn't fail, you'll eventually have to redraw it in illustrator as a vector anyhow.

Comment: It's actually just as easy with masks in Illustrator as it is with Photoshop. (in this particular case)

Comment: @Johannes That's good to hear. Doing web design I almost never use illustrator unless I'm designing some kind of abstract icon, so I'm pretty rusty with a lot of the features.

Comment: I'd always reccommend going the illustrator route when creating logo's, even for web. You never know when you might need a giant blowup for a poster...